# He de preocuparme por el tamaño de la base de datos SQLite en mi aplicación Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

soy nuevo en la comunidad y en el mundo de la programación, espero estar respetando todas las reglas :D

He desarrollado una aplicación que guarda un registro de alumnos. Los datos guardados son:

- Nombre
- Apellidos
- Edad
- Carrera
- Hora de llegada a la biblioteca.
- Hora de salida de la biblioteca.

Los procesos de "manipulación" (guardado, actualización, eliminación) de la base de datos se realiza sin problema alguno. Sin embargo me surge la duda de si he de preocuparme por el tamaño de la base de datos. Se trata de una aplicación desarrollada con fines educativos, sin embargo me gustaría seguir progresando en el mundo del desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles y por lo tanto creo que es importante saber este tipo de cosas.

Me imagino que mi base de datos no puede consumir muchos recursos, sin embargo me gustaría confirmarlo.

La solución que se me podría llegar a ocurrir es crear un método que eliminase entradas antiguas (siempre y cuando la persistencia de datos a largo plazo no sea importante). Algo como:

```
"DELETE FROM DBTable WHERE Time <= date('now','-10 day')";
```

Para ello agregaría a mi base de datos la columna Time y debería funcionar.

¿Alguna recomendación?¿Cómo trabajáis vosotros con SQLite y la persistencia de datos?

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda!

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por mi parte he realizado pruebas con base de datos que pesen aproximadamente unos 3 GB y no he tenido problemas, ahora esto mucho depende de como se maneje, por ejemplo cuando lo tienes todo en una sola tabla o por separado.

En caso de usar **una sola tabla**, mientras mas datos tengas en esa tabla las insersiones y actualizaciones pueden llegar a demorar bastante, con decirte que pueden llegar a demorar incluso horas. La conclusión es que una tabla sqlite única y muy grande tendrá problemas con las inserciones y probablemente también con otras operaciones.

Supongo que esto no es una sorpresa, ya que la tabla se hace más grande, la inserción y actualización de todos los índices lleva más tiempo.

También otra opción es manejar en **múltiples tablas** tus datos osea separar una tabla por un rango de tiempo.

Otro problema que puedas tener en caso de tener una base de datos muy grande es el comando VACUUM. A medida que se realicen más inserciones / eliminaciones, la fragmentación del archivo en el disco empeorará, por lo que el objetivo es realizar VACUUM periódicamente para optimizar el archivo y recuperar el espacio del archivo.

Sin embargo, como se señala en la documentación (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) , se hace una copia completa de la base de datos para hacer un Vacuum, lo que lleva mucho tiempo en completarse. Entonces, cuanto más pequeña sea la base de datos, más rápido terminará esta operación.

En conclusión mucho dependera de la cantidad de datos que guardes, asi como puedes separar una tabla en varias, tambien puedes crear una base de datos por dia, teniendo en cuenta que para hacer las consultas se complicaria un poco pero seria tal vez la forma mas rápida.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y la ayuda!